# Remove HTML content groups from start to end of string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need a regex that could remove the full tag from start to end.
For eg.:
For the given string:

```
var str = "Hello <script> console.log('script tag') </script> World";
```

I need an output:

```
"Hello  World" // with full script tag including inner content removed
```

I am very specific for only the **`RegEx`** solution, so don't need browser append tricks.
Kindly notify if this is not possible at all.

I tried this and its variations:

```
inputString.replace( /<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "" );
```

But this is not achieving what I want and is removing only the tag elements, leaving the inner content. What `RegEx` groups should I create in the expression?

I do not need to address stuff like `type="text/javascript"`, as they are already filtered before I receive the string.
No jQuery plz. (I need to store the RegEx as a property to my filter object).

Help appreciated.

Comment: Required read for everyone who asks about parsing HTML with regular expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Have bookmarked that answer long back in my Stack folder, don't want to simply increase its view. I don't need a Chuck Norris RegEx for matching tags. My conditions are limited. Given a limited set of conditions, it can be done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pure regex solution:

```
var str = "Hello <script> console.log('script tag') </script> World";
var repl = str.replace(/<([^.]+)>.*?<\/\1>/ig, '');
//=> "Hello  World"
```

with an assumption that there is no `<` OR `>` between opening and closing tags.

Comment: I didn't know that we can use `\1` in that very expression, Have always used in the expression after the comma. Worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yes `\1` is back-reference that can be used in the regex itself.

Comment: If  I want to remove the specific tag with its content, could you please help me?

Comment: @anubhava it doesn't work `str.replace(/<(a)\s*[^>]*>.*?<\/\1>/ig, '')` and I want to remove all `a` tags with its content please help me to solve this.

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari: Comments is not the right place to ask new  questions. Please post a new question and you will get answers.

Comment: @anubhava I asked the question could you please answer it? appreciate the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262311/remove-specific-html-tag-with-its-content-from-javascript-string