# Remove specific HTML tag with its content from javascript string

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom

I have the following string variable and I want to remove all `a` tags with its content from the string.

```
var myString = "<table><tr><td>Some text ...<a href='#'>label...</a></td></tr></table>";
myString += "<table><tr><td>Some text ...<a href='#'>label...</a></td></tr></table>";
myString += "<table><tr><td>Some text ...<a href='#'>label...</a></td></tr></table>";
```

I have checked this [Remove HTML content groups from start to end of string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632168/remove-html-content-groups-from-start-to-end-of-string-in-javascript) question's answers but it is for all tags.

Thank you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should avoid parsing HTML using regex. Here is a way of removing all the `<a>` tags using `DOM`:

```js
// your HTML text
var myString = '<table><tr><td>Some text ...<a href="#">label...</a></td></tr></table>';
myString += '<table><tr><td>Some text ...<a href="#">label...</a></td></tr></table>'
myString += '<table><tr><td>Some text ...<a href="#">label...</a></td></tr></table>'

// create a new dov container
var div = document.createElement('div');

// assing your HTML to div's innerHTML
div.innerHTML = myString;

// get all <a> elements from div
var elements = div.getElementsByTagName('a');

// remove all <a> elements
while (elements[0])
   elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0])

// get div's innerHTML into a new variable
var repl = div.innerHTML;

// display it
console.log(repl)

/*
<table><tbody><tr><td>Some text ...</td></tr></tbody></table>
<table><tbody><tr><td>Some text ...</td></tr></tbody></table>
<table><tbody><tr><td>Some text ...</td></tr></tbody></table>
*/
```

Comment: > "You should avoid parsing HTML using regex"... interesting. I never thought about that. Why?

Comment: @Bangkokian 10 years old question! but the answers in this thread are still relevant IMO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747 .

Comment: This is beautiful, just saved me hours

Comment: if you want to remove script tags and avoid loading malicious code before attaching them to the DOM, this approach is not valid. The answer from Nisarg, considering the comment from MattS may work better...

Comment: @Frohlich: There are other safer ways to do that but using regex is definitely error prone for modifying HTML/XML.

Answer (score 14):

Here's the code. The regex `/<a.*>.*?<\/a>/ig` fits well for your data.

```js
var myString = "<table><tr><td>Some text ...<a href='#'>label...</a></td></tr></table>";
myString += "<table><tr><td>Some text ...<a href='#'>label...</a></td></tr></table>";
myString += "<table><tr><td>Some text ...<a href='#'>label...</a></td></tr></table>";

console.log(myString);

var anchorTagsRemoved = myString.replace(/<a.*?>.*?<\/a>/ig,'');
console.log(anchorTagsRemoved);
```

Comment: perfect,clean and simple.. 

Comment: To use on larger tags that span multiple lines, add a new line check. html.replace(/<header.*?>(.|\n|\r)*?<\/header>/ig,'');

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myString = "<table><tr><td>Some text ...<a href='#'>label...</a></td></tr></table>";
myString += "<table><tr><td>Some text ...<a href='#'>label...</a></td></tr></table>";
myString += "<table><tr><td>Some text ...<a href='#'>label...</a></td></tr></table>";

el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = myString;

var output = document.getElementById('output');
el.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(item, index){
 item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
})
output.innerText = el.innerHTML;
```

```html
<h3>Output:</h3>
<pre id='output'></pre>
```