# Replace class name <span> tag to <sup> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace span class to the `<sup>` tag

```
<sup>
  <span class="wysiwyg-color-yellow">test</span>
</sup>
```

see html,

If `<sup>` tag exist then i want to replace `<span>` class to the `<sup>` tag
like this,

```
<sup class="wysiwyg-color-yellow">test</sup>
```

in if condition

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()`, `.className`, `.innerHTML`, `.remove()`

Comment: is there more a sup tag in the code?

Comment: @Mario yes only one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262311/remove-specific-html-tag-with-its-content-from-javascript-string Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please inspect the output of the following example

```js
const color = document.querySelector(".wysiwyg-color-yellow");
const sup = document.querySelector("sup");

if (color.nodeName === "SPAN") {
  sup.innerHTML = color.textContent; // here is removed the inner span
  sup.classList.add(color.getAttribute("class"));
}
```

```html
<sup>
  <span class="wysiwyg-color-yellow">test</span>
</sup>
```

In the case that there is more than one sup element

```js
const colors = document.querySelectorAll("sup > span");

colors.forEach((color) => {
  const parent = color.parentNode;

  parent.innerHTML = color.textContent;
  parent.classList.add(color.getAttribute("class"));
});
```

```html
<sup>
  <span class="wysiwyg-color-yellow">test</span>
</sup>
<sup>
  <span class="wysiwyg-color-green">test</span>
</sup>
<sup>
  <span class="wysiwyg-color-blue">test</span>
</sup>
<sup>
  <span class="wysiwyg-color-orange">test</span>
</sup>
```

Comment: While this does technically work, it does not modify every sup element, and only changes the class to "wysiwyg-color-yellow", when the span's class could be something else.

Comment: about `only changes the class to" wysiwyg-color-yellow ", when the span's class could be something else` I have updated the answer to assign to sup the class name of the selected element. About ` it does not modify every sup element` you have told me that there is only one sup element

Comment: @Mario ty so much it help me.

Comment: @Mario can you help me to solve this ..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527376/enable-underline-for-lowercase-characters-g-q-p-j-y

Answer (score 1):

Here is probably the best solution:

```js
var buttons = $("sup");

for(var i=0; i< buttons.length; i++){
    if (buttons[i].children[0]) {
        if (buttons[i].children[0].nodeName == "SPAN") {
            var spanElement = buttons[i].children[0];
            buttons[i].setAttribute("class", spanElement.getAttribute("class"));
            buttons[i].innerHTML = spanElement.innerText;
        }
    }
}
```

This selects every `sup` element, and checks whether there is a `span` within it. If there is a `span` element, then it sets the `sup` element's class to the `span`'s class, and sets the innerHTML to the `span`'s innerText.

I hope that makes sense.

If you need the JQuery library, then I recommend using [jquery-3.2.1.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js).

Comment: can you help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527376/enable-underline-for-lowercase-characters-g-q-p-j-y