# How to show formatted html string using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this problem, I created a html page to show some texts formatted using quill editor.
I save every text created in a table using this format as example:

```
<p>Test<strong> format</strong></p>
```

To show the text in my front end, I'm using a `v-for` with `vue.js`, like this:

```
<div class="card" v-for="(wiki, index) in wikiList">
   <div class="mb-3">
       <div class="form-control" type="text" id="view-container-wiki" readonly>{{wiki.description}}</input>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that my html is not formatting the text, its just showing it with tags:

[image]

How can I create a method to return the string formatted ? I tried using `Jquery`, but it didn't work.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use `v-html` directive :

```
 <div class="form-control" 
      type="text" id="view-container-wiki" 
      readonly 
      v-html="wiki.description">
 </div>
```

Comment: @NewProgrammer I suggest you to parse it before rendering to avoid script injection.
Like remove tags `<script>`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will look it

Comment: No problem, it seems there is no "native" function to do that. Maybe this will help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45262458/13604954