# How to trim html elements and class from string in JS

Tags: javascript, html, trim

I have the following string and code:

```js
str = `<p class="">Lores Ipsimulm</p><p class="">1 x 100ml  - 19% </p><p class="">1 x 100ml No.6 Mike</p><p class="">1 x 100ml No.3</p><`
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.textContent = str;
var converted = p.innerHTML;

document.getElementById("final").value = converted;
```

How do I trim all HTML elements including classes, their name, and other attributes?

Comment: Can you mention how exactly you want the result? for example, what do you mean by trimming HTML elements? If you want the HTML elements in the string to get applied to the element with id `final`, you can use: `document.getElementById('final').innerHTML = str;`. If it doesn't answer your question, mention additional details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific HTML tag with its content from javascript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262311/remove-specific-html-tag-with-its-content-from-javascript-string)

Comment: Why take the `innerHTML`? Take the [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText).

Comment: the result i am looking for is:

Lores Ipsimulm 1 x 100ml  - 19%  1 x 100ml No.6 Mike1 x 100ml No.3

Comment: `innerText` can do that. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

#### set with `.innerHTML`, get with `.innerText`

You can use [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) to get the text-only representation of an element's innerHTML. So you set the `.innerHTML` value and get the text using `.innerText`.
`innerText` will use the raw text with the exact spaces existing in the HTML. If you want to format the text for every `p` tag, you must loop through them.
See example snippet below for `.innerText` usage.

```js
var str = `<p class="">Lores Ipsimulm</p><p class="">1 x 100ml - 19% </p><p class="">1 x 100ml No.6 Mike</p><p class="">1 x 100ml No.3</p>`;
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = str;
var converted = p.innerText;

console.log(converted);
```

You **set** the HTML value with `innerHTML`, but you **get** the text using `innerText` as shown in the snippet.

Your example HTML has an open `<` at the end. Make sure to use valid HTML.