# Change style of iframe coming from Wordpress API in React

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design, fetch, wordpress-rest-api

I'm fetching (React) to get a response from Wordpress API.
The problem is that *sometimes* posts content includes iframe videos with lazy loading inside them which have hardcoded inline styles.
I tried to target them with classes or by their tag names without getting a change, neither if I use !important in css.
How could I change their style so I can make them responsive or even make them with style display:none?

Comment: Just parse the response to remove all the iframes before rendering the post. [This technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45262458/2518285) may be useful.